# Names of argument types

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have the following exercise:

```
Given the following argument:

  If Peter is going, Bobbina stays at home. Bobbina stays at home. Therefore Peter is going.

What is the name of this type of argument?
```

I can't seem to find `argument names`. I could think of 'Valid' or 'Invalid' as an answer to this question, but that doesn't seem like an argument name to me.

Do you have any clue?

Thanks

Comment: I never heard of a name for this argument. I could be wrong but I believe there's no name for this, especially because this argument is mathematically invalid (I don't think we need names for wrong arguments...).

Comment: What if I wrote something like, if pigs could fly, 1+1=2. Well, 1+1 does, in fact, equal 2. Does that mean pigs can fly?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent

Comment: Could we assume the answer to this question / the `name` for this argument is a 'converse error'?

Comment: Fallacy....... .